# Getting error "Class name "org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TotalTPSGraphConsumer" in JAVA

Tags: java, jmeter

While trying to generate Summary Report graphically in Jmeter in Java(Not in GUI) I am getiing below error.

```
ERROR   2020-03-10 14:10:48.284 [jmeter.r] (): Class name "org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TotalTPSGraphConsumer" is not valid.
```

Full code just in case:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

import static org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY;

public class RunJMeterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/test.jmx"));
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }
        String logFile = "/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/result.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
        JMeterUtils.setProperty(JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY, "/path/to/dashboard");
        ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile, null);
        generator.generate();
    }
}
```

Do anyone knows the reason behind? Highly appreciate any suggestions.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [TotalTPSGraphConsumer.java source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/processor/graph/impl/TotalTPSGraphConsumer.java#L40)

```
/**
 * The class TotalTPSGraphConsumer provides a graph to visualize transactions
 * rate per second.
 *
 * @since 5.0
 */
```

So make sure to use the same JMeter version for:

1. Creating the [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
2. For running the test from the Java code, your [Project Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) must use the same versions of the dependencies libraries as the JMeter from the point 1.

As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article **you should always be using the latest version of JMeter** so make sure you use [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

In particular to get rid of the above error you need to have [ApacheJMeter_core version 5.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/5.2.1) in your project classpath.